# Vue.js - define v-model with defineProps and defineModel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When I am creating a component that receives 2 properties, but one of them must be "two way binding"  as in the example below:

```
<script
  setup
  lang="ts"
>
type TextFieldCompProps = {
  required?: boolean;
  modelValue: string;
}

defineProps<TextFieldCompProps>()
const modelValue = defineModel<string>({ required: true })
</script>
```

Is it correct to declare "modelValue" in `TextFieldProps` and use `defineModel` for this purpose?

Or the `TextFieldProps` must be only `type TextFieldProps = { required?: boolean }`

Comment: `defineModel` automatically declares a `modelValue` prop for you (which doesn't require your const to have the literal name "modelValue" by the way). You can verify this when using defineModel by itself and inspecting your component in Vue devtools.  You don't _also_ need to declare a prop with it.  If the prop is meant to be different than the defineModel then you should give them different names, otherwise it can be removed.